# c# return error with using block

Tags: c#, database, string, ms-access, return-value

```
 private string Read_MDB_Acc(String acc)
    {   string myReturn;
        ...
        while (odrReader.Read())
                        {                            
                            myReturn = odrReader["acc"].ToString();


                        }


                        odrReader.Close();

                        odcConnection.Close();
    }
 return myReturn; //Show the myReturn doesn't not exist, how to solved?
```

Comment: What do you want? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing your question, for this to compile, try this:

```
private string Read_MDB_Acc(String acc)
{
    string myReturn = String.Empty;
    // ...
    while (odrReader.Read())
    {                            
        myReturn = odrReader["acc"].ToString();
    }

    odrReader.Close();
    odcConnection.Close();

    return myReturn;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your `myReturn`  variable with empty string like:

```
private string Read_MDB_Acc(String acc)
    {   string myReturn = string.Empty;
        ...
        while (odrReader.Read())
                        {                            
                            myReturn = odrReader["acc"].ToString();


                        }


                        odrReader.Close();

                        odcConnection.Close();
                        return myReturn;
    }
```